# I've been trying to get sublim text 2 to build my html projet with chrome and it doesn't seem to work,

Tags: html, google-chrome, sublimetext2

```
{
"cmd": ["open" "-a" "Google Chrome" "$file"]
```

}

that's the code I'm using.

And here is the error I get:

Error trying to parse build systems: Unexpected character, exepected a comma or closing bracket in C:..\Chrome.sublime-build:2:17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add commas

```
 "cmd": ["open", "-a", "Google Chrome", "$file"]
```

EDIT:
And if I remember well there is an *View in Browser* package for sublime so check that too